# Javascript audio pause button works, but does not resume again

Tags: javascript, audio, playback

I am trying to build a Swing Era jukebox on Javascript. Just about everything works except for the 'needle'.  I hope I am not the only one here who still uses vinyl!  Suffice it to say that the pause button should be able to resume from the spot where the audio was paused, much like lifting the needle and dropping it in the same spot.  It can only pause as of now.

Here is the JS code, or what I think is the relevant extract:

```
  var playtext = $("div#play").text()
  var playing = false

  function Jukebox(){
    this.tune = $("audio")[0];

    Jukebox.prototype.play = function(){ 
      this.tune.play();
      playing = true;
    }

    Jukebox.prototype.pause = function(){
      this.tune.pause(); //Apparently, pause is a built-in function?!
      playing = false;
    }

    Jukebox.prototype.needle = function(){
      if (playing = true) {
        this.tune.pause();
        playing = false; 
      }
      if (playing = false) {
        this.tune.play();
        playing = true; //After it is paused, it cannot play again?!  Why?
      }
    }
```

Comment: `(playing = true)`  <-- assignment

Comment: Can you give a fiddle sample. Is it the HTML5 based audio box? May be you can check the conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

check out this statement

```
if(playing === true)
```

rather than

```
if(playing = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I used redundant language here.  The answer is:

```
Jukebox.prototype.needle = function(){
  if (playing) {
    this.tune.pause();
    playing = false; 
  }
  else {
    this.tune.play();
    playing = true; //After it is paused, it cannot play again?!  Why?
  }
```